# Understanding and Analyzing a Meteor JS Object (might be a cursor object)

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor.JS app I declared a Collection:

```
WPThemes = new Mongo.Collection('wpthemes');
```

This collection has fixtures that I have inserted.
It has atleast 64 documents in it with the following structure

```
{
    productname: 'sample product name',
    name: 'sameple name'
}
```

I then issue a publication for it:

```
Meteor.publish('wpthemes', function(options){
    check(options, {
        limit: Number
    });

    return WPThemes.find({}, options);
});
```

In the RouteController I subscribe to it and assign it to the 'data' of the webpage:

```
WPThemesListController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'wordpress',
    increment: 66,
    wpthemesLimit: function(){
        return parseInt(this.params.wpthemesLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    findOptions: function(){
        return {limit: this.wpthemesLimit()};
    },
    subscriptions: function(){
        this.themesSub = Meteor.subscribe('wpthemes', this.findOptions());
    },
    themes: function(){

        return WPThemes.find({}, this.findOptions());
    },
    data: function(){
        var hasMore = this.themes().count() === this.wpthemesLimit();

        return{

            themes: this.themes(),
            ready: this.themesSub.ready,
            nextPath: hasMore ? this.nextPath() : null
        }
    }

});
```

So now I'm inside the Template.wordpress.rendered = function(){} block.
I want to access themes as returned in the 'data:' above.
themes gets assigned the value returned by this.themes() and this.themes() gets the value returned by return WPThemes.find({}, this.findOptions());
and as far as i know Collection.find() returns a cursor.

Therefore am I right that themes is holding a cursor object???

When I print to console this.data.themes by: console.log(this.data.themes);
I get this:

```
[Log] Object (wordpress.js, line 14)
_selectorId: undefined
_transform: null
collection: Object
fields: undefined
limit: 66
matcher: Object
reactive: true
skip: undefined
sorter: null
__proto__: Object
```

How I iterate over this 'cursor' object and print to the console all of the info stored in the documents?
In this case I want to print every name and product name that was inserted into this collection by:

```
WPThemes.insert({

            productname: stringToUse,
            name: studioPressFiles[i]
        });
```

I have inserted atlas 64 documents into this Collection.

And yet, if I do console.log(this.data.themes.count());

I am getting 0....Why is that?

How do I iterate over this cursor to get the data when its supposed items are 0?
The webpage confirms that there are items in the collection because {{#each themes}} works.....

How do I convert this cursor into an array?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch

So basically all you gotta do is `console.log(this.data.themes.fetch());`

Comment: Hi I've tried this but it only returns and prints an empty array...e.g. [].......What's the reason behind this? The Collection has entries for sure.....Because I'm able to populate the website based on this using Spacebars in the .html file....

Comment: What about console.log(WPThemes.find())? IMO you overcomplicated code, so I can't rly tell what you wanted to do here If it doesn't work that means ur subscription fails

Comment: Hi, I did some more testing.  As it turns out, when I call console.log(this.data.themes.fetch()); e.g. Templates.name.rendered = function(){console.log(this.data.themes.fetch());} The publication has not finished sending the data and that's whyI'm getting blank array.  So now the questions is, is there a way to use Template.name.rendered or Template.name.xxx to get this.data.themes only after the publication and subscription has done its job????

Comment: If you use iron-router then you should make publish in waitOn function(in old API) or this.subscribe('name').wait() in new API. Or instead of data.themes.fetch() use WPThemes.find() - its reactive so at first you'll see blank page but after publication is done your page will fill up with needed data

Comment: O yes....subscriptions: function(){
  this.themesSub = Meteor.subscribe('wpthemes', this.findOptions());
 },
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('wpthemes', this.findOptions());
  },....this worked :-)  Thank you very much :-)